# Calculate average gas prices by year in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 3 columns, A=Date, B=Price, C=Grade in Excel. I want to calculate the average price of fuel for each year and an overall average of all years by grade.

The data table looks like this

```
      Date | Price | Grade
2012-05-01 | $3.49 | Regular
2012-06-07 | $3.58 | Regular
2012-04-01 | $3.98 | Premium
2012-02-17 | $3.87 | Premium
2013-01-01 | $3.49 | Regular
2013-02-01 | $3.89 | Premium
2013-03-06 | $3.89 | Premium
2013-03-09 | $3.45 | Regular
```

The output should look something like this:

```
Year | Regular | Premium
2012 |    3.43 |    3.67
2013 |    3.45 |    3.73
 All |    3.44 |    3.70
```

Comment: Write a VBA to create arrays for premium and regular (all columns). You can then sort the arrays using their date and extract (and then process) the average prices for your desired date. Extract and process the entire array to get your "all" averages.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck? This isn't a script writing service, so you'll have to try some solutions on your own and ask for help if you run into problems.

Answer (score 3):

Use the function `AVERAGEIFS`. It allows to calculate an average based on multiple criteria. You need two criteria for your evaluation: a date comparison (e.g. date in 2012) and a string comparison (e.g. "Regular").

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for VBA or formulae. Excel's pivot table feature is designed for this type of data summary.

- Select your data range
- Insert -> Pivot table - This will create a pivot table (on a new worksheet by default) and, when you select a cell in the pivot table, you'll see a window appear called Pivot Table Field list.
- Drag Date to the Row Labels
- Drag Grade to the Column Labels
- Drag Price to the Values

  - Click on Sum of Price and select Value field settings...
  - Select Average instead of Sum and click OK
- Finally, to group by year, right click on one of the date values in the pivot table itself (not the field list window) and then select Group and then select Years.